# Value return undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am following this tutorial for create my first app using modules. For some reason the code is not working and I really tried everything and I can't figure it out.

I create the function testing inside the module budgetController to see if is adding the item to the list, but when I click on the button to add the item the following error is coming up  TypeError: data.allItems[type] is undefined.

```js
var budgetController = (function() {
  var Expense = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
  };
  var Income = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
  };
  var data = {
    allItems: {
      exp: [],
      inc: []
    },
    totals: {
      inc: 0,
      exp: 0
    }
  };
  return {
    addItem: function(type, des, val) {
      var newItem, ID;
      if (data.allItems[type].length > 0) {
        ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
      } else {
        ID = 0;
      }
      if (type === 'expense') {
        newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);

      } else if (type === 'income') {
        newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
      }
      data.allItems[type].push(newItem);

      return newItem;
    },
    testing: function() {
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
})();

var UIcontroller = (function() {
  var domStrings = {
    inputType: ".add__type",
    inputDescription: ".add__description",
    inputValue: ".add__value",
    inputBtn: '.add__btn'
  };

  return {
    getInput: function() {
      return {
        type: document.querySelector(domStrings.inputType).value,
        description: document.querySelector(domStrings.inputDescription).value,
        value: document.querySelector(domStrings.inputValue).value
      };
    },
    getDomStrings: function() {
      return domStrings;
    }
  };

})();

var controller = (function(cntrlBudget, cntrlUI) {

  var addEventListener = function() {
    var dom = cntrlUI.getDomStrings();

    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
        addItems();
      }
    });


    document.querySelector(dom.inputBtn).addEventListener("click", addItems);
  };

  var addItems = function() {

    var input, newItem;
    input = cntrlUI.getInput();
    newItem = cntrlBudget.addItem(input.type, input.description, input.value);
  }
  return {
    init: function() {
      addEventListener();
    }
  }

})(budgetController, UIcontroller);

controller.init();
```

```css
/**********************************************
*** GENERAL
**********************************************/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

body {
  color: #555;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.red {
  color: #FF5049 !important;
}

.red-focus:focus {
  border: 1px solid #FF5049 !important;
}


/**********************************************
*** TOP PART
**********************************************/

.top {
  height: 40vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)), url(back.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.budget {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.budget__title {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.budget__value {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.budget__income,
.budget__expenses {
  padding: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.budget__income {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #28B9B5;
}

.budget__expenses {
  background-color: #FF5049;
}

.budget__income--text,
.budget__expenses--text {
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #444;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.budget__income--value,
.budget__expenses--value {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  float: left;
}

.budget__income--percentage,
.budget__expenses--percentage {
  float: left;
  width: 34px;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.budget__expenses--percentage {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/**********************************************
*** BOTTOM PART
**********************************************/


/***** FORM *****/

.add {
  padding: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.add__container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.add__type {
  width: 55px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add__description,
.add__value {
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add__description {
  width: 400px;
}

.add__value {
  width: 100px;
}

.add__btn {
  font-size: 35px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #28B9B5;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.add__btn:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.add__type:focus,
.add__description:focus,
.add__value:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #28B9B5;
}

.add__btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/***** LISTS *****/

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

.income {
  float: left;
  width: 475px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.expenses {
  float: left;
  width: 475px;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.icome__title {
  color: #28B9B5;
}

.expenses__title {
  color: #FF5049;
}

.item {
  padding: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.item:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.item__description {
  float: left;
}

.item__value {
  float: left;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.item__percentage {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  font-size: 11px;
  background-color: #FFDAD9;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.income .item__value,
.income .item__delete--btn {
  color: #28B9B5;
}

.expenses .item__value,
.expenses .item__percentage,
.expenses .item__delete--btn {
  color: #FF5049;
}

.item__delete {
  float: left;
}

.item__delete--btn {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
  display: none;
}

.item__delete--btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.item__delete--btn:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.item:hover .item__delete--btn {
  display: block;
}

.item:hover .item__value {
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.item:hover .item__percentage {
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.unpaid {
  background-color: #FFDAD9 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FF5049;
}

.unpaid .item__percentage {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.unpaid:hover .item__description {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Budgety</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="top">
    <div class="budget">
      <div class="budget__title">
        Available Budget in <span class="budget__title--month">%Month%</span>:
      </div>

      <div class="budget__value">+ 2,345.64</div>

      <div class="budget__income clearfix">
        <div class="budget__income--text">Income</div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="budget__income--value">+ 4,300.00</div>
          <div class="budget__income--percentage">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="budget__expenses clearfix">
        <div class="budget__expenses--text">Expenses</div>
        <div class="right clearfix">
          <div class="budget__expenses--value">- 1,954.36</div>
          <div class="budget__expenses--percentage">45%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="add">
      <div class="add__container">
        <select class="add__type">
          <option value="income" selected>+</option>
          <option value="expense">-</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
        <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
        <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="income">
        <h2 class="icome__title">Income</h2>
        <div class="income__list">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="expenses">
        <h2 class="expenses__title">Expenses</h2>
        <div class="expenses__list">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any advice will be very helpful.

Thanks for your time

Comment: You should indent your code

Comment: Also, remove the code that is not relevant to the issue.

Comment: Please create a [**MINIMAL**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: The error says it all: `data.allItems[type] is undefined`, since type has the value  'income' or 'expence', but your data contains 'inc' and 'exp'.

Answer (score 1):

Your options value, of your select tag, are not corrects. Change with the same key that your object `allItems`.
Make the same for if statement into addItem method.

```js
var budgetController = (function() {


  var Expense = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
  };

  var Income = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
  };

  var data = {
    allItems: {
      exp: [],
      inc: []
    },


    totals: {
      inc: 0,
      exp: 0
    }

  };
  return {
    addItem: function(type, des, val) {
      var newItem, ID;
      if (data.allItems[type].length > 0) {
        ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
      } else {
        ID = 0;
      }

      if (type === 'exp') {
        newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);

      } else if (type === 'inc') {
        newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
      }


      data.allItems[type].push(newItem);

      return newItem;
    },
    testing: function() {
      console.log(data);
    }
  }

})();








var UIcontroller = (function() {
  var domStrings = {
    inputType: ".add__type",
    inputDescription: ".add__description",
    inputValue: ".add__value",
    inputBtn: '.add__btn'
  };

  return {
    getInput: function() {

      return {

        type: document.querySelector(domStrings.inputType).value,
        description: document.querySelector(domStrings.inputDescription).value,
        value: document.querySelector(domStrings.inputValue).value
      };
    },
    getDomStrings: function() {
      return domStrings;

    }
  };

})();







var controller = (function(cntrlBudget, cntrlUI) {




  var addEventListener = function() {
    var dom = cntrlUI.getDomStrings();

    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
        addItems();
      }
    });


    document.querySelector(dom.inputBtn).addEventListener("click", addItems);

  };


  var addItems = function() {

    var input, newItem;
    input = cntrlUI.getInput();
    newItem = cntrlBudget.addItem(input.type, input.description, input.value);



  }



  return {

    init: function() {
      addEventListener();



    }
  }

})(budgetController, UIcontroller);

controller.init();
```

```css
/**********************************************
*** GENERAL
**********************************************/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

body {
  color: #555;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.red {
  color: #FF5049 !important;
}

.red-focus:focus {
  border: 1px solid #FF5049 !important;
}


/**********************************************
*** TOP PART
**********************************************/

.top {
  height: 40vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)), url(back.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.budget {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.budget__title {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.budget__value {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.budget__income,
.budget__expenses {
  padding: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.budget__income {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #28B9B5;
}

.budget__expenses {
  background-color: #FF5049;
}

.budget__income--text,
.budget__expenses--text {
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #444;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.budget__income--value,
.budget__expenses--value {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  float: left;
}

.budget__income--percentage,
.budget__expenses--percentage {
  float: left;
  width: 34px;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.budget__expenses--percentage {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/**********************************************
*** BOTTOM PART
**********************************************/


/***** FORM *****/

.add {
  padding: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.add__container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.add__type {
  width: 55px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add__description,
.add__value {
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add__description {
  width: 400px;
}

.add__value {
  width: 100px;
}

.add__btn {
  font-size: 35px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #28B9B5;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.add__btn:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.add__type:focus,
.add__description:focus,
.add__value:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #28B9B5;
}

.add__btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/***** LISTS *****/

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

.income {
  float: left;
  width: 475px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.expenses {
  float: left;
  width: 475px;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.icome__title {
  color: #28B9B5;
}

.expenses__title {
  color: #FF5049;
}

.item {
  padding: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.item:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.item__description {
  float: left;
}

.item__value {
  float: left;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.item__percentage {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  font-size: 11px;
  background-color: #FFDAD9;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.income .item__value,
.income .item__delete--btn {
  color: #28B9B5;
}

.expenses .item__value,
.expenses .item__percentage,
.expenses .item__delete--btn {
  color: #FF5049;
}

.item__delete {
  float: left;
}

.item__delete--btn {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
  display: none;
}

.item__delete--btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.item__delete--btn:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.item:hover .item__delete--btn {
  display: block;
}

.item:hover .item__value {
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.item:hover .item__percentage {
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.unpaid {
  background-color: #FFDAD9 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FF5049;
}

.unpaid .item__percentage {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.unpaid:hover .item__description {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Budgety</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="top">
    <div class="budget">
      <div class="budget__title">
        Available Budget in <span class="budget__title--month">%Month%</span>:
      </div>

      <div class="budget__value">+ 2,345.64</div>

      <div class="budget__income clearfix">
        <div class="budget__income--text">Income</div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="budget__income--value">+ 4,300.00</div>
          <div class="budget__income--percentage">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="budget__expenses clearfix">
        <div class="budget__expenses--text">Expenses</div>
        <div class="right clearfix">
          <div class="budget__expenses--value">- 1,954.36</div>
          <div class="budget__expenses--percentage">45%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="add">
      <div class="add__container">
        <select class="add__type">
          <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
          <option value="exp">-</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
        <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
        <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="income">
        <h2 class="icome__title">Income</h2>

        <div class="income__list">



        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="expenses">
        <h2 class="expenses__title">Expenses</h2>

        <div class="expenses__list">


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'inc' and 'exp' as your variable names, in initialization, while using the full forms 'income' and 'expense' elsewhere. Just change your variable 'data' to this,

```
     var data = {
                allItems: {
                    expense: [],
                    income: []
                },


                totals: {
                    income: 0,
                    expense: 0
                }
```